# Why electrical current is base quantity instead of electrical charge?

Tags: conventions, units

I thought base quantities are defined as independent quantity.

But I realized `Electrical Current` which usually notated as `I` for variabel name and `A (Ampere)` as Unit is defined as `Electrical Charge / Time`. So that's mean electrical current is dependent toward `Electrical Charge and Time`.

This is analogy with Velocity that derived (dependen) from Length and Time.

While Electrical Charge that usually notated as `Q` as variabel name and `C (coulomb)` as unit is independent, why doesn't the convention categorize it as base quantity?[image]

Comment: A base quantity (or basic quantity) is chosen and arbitrarily defined, rather than being derived from a combination of other physical quantities. Also here 's a link to a similar question [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/273628/what-is-a-base-unit-in-the-new-si-and-why-is-the-ampere-one-of-them?rq=1)

Comment: Okay so I think my question is duplicate?

Comment: Yes , when ur writing a question , there is a dropdown list which gives you an idea of all the related questions out there , be sure to check that when u post a question , might give you better insight